# Git: Integrate with Funtoo Keychain

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ssh, keychain

I'm trying to integrate my VSCode with my Funtoo Keychain.

Funtoo Keychain is a great way to synchronize ssh/GPG agents across multiple terminal sessions. For example, I can type my SSH password once, and it will automatically save it to a Funtoo agent that will prevent me from typing it again in a different session.

I was able to easily integrate Funtoo Keychain with Emacs and other text editors, but VSCode seems to ignore (even that my `.zshrc` starts Funtoo automatically.

Anyone knows how can I achieve this?